# Show related data using Razor Syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have two classes: `Store` and `Machine`.

Right now I have constructed a view where I show the `Stores` associated to the logged user:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var Tiendas = await _context.Stores.Where(t => t.Usuario == User.Identity.Name).Include(t => t.Machines).ToListAsync();

        LiqIndexData Liquid = new LiqIndexData()
        {
            StoreL = Tiendas,

        };

        return View(Liquid);
    }
```

In this code I also added the `Machines` asociated to each `Store`.

**The View:**

In my View I would like to present, for each `Store`, all of the `Machines`registered. For this I'm using nav-tabs

*Nav Tab based on the number of `Stores`*

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    @foreach (var item in Model.StoreL)
    {
        <li><a href="#@item.StoreID" data-toggle="tab">@item.StoreName</a></li>
    }
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    @foreach (var item in Model.StoreL)
    { 
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="@item.StoreID"></div>
    }
```

**The Problem:**

*Info shown in the body of each Nav-tab:*

I'm trying to access the information of each `Machine` associated with each `Store`. For this I'm trying to use:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.StoreL)
{
    <tr>
         <td>
              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Machines
              .Where(m=>m.StoreID==item.StoreID))
         </td>
```

But I don't know how to access the property. If I try:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Machines
              .Where(m=>m.StoreID==item.StoreID).PropertyXYZ)
```

I get:

> 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'PropertyXYZ' and no extension method 'PropertyXYZ' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any advice?

Comment: You shouldn't need your `Where()` call at all; the `Machines` navigation property will automatically filter by the foreign key.

Comment: You need a 2nd nested loop - `foreach (var machine in item.Machines) { <td>@machine.PropertyXYZ</td> }`

Comment: There's no `PropertyXYZ` because `Where()` returns a collection and the collection has not that property.

Comment: Thanks all. Indeed I was missing a second `foreach` to go thru every Machine and show the property. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error is trying to tell you, your collection of `Machine`s has no `PropertyXYZ`.

Depending on what you actually want to do, you can either use `First()` to get only one `Machine` (and no others), or use a loop to go through all of them.

Comment: uhm yeah, I'm missing a second loop to go thru each `Machine`. Will explore this.